# Session - start with buffer 1

Tags: buffers, sessions

*Note: Possible fixed bug. See comments.*

---

A somewhat minor nuisance, but as the pedantic for these things :P

When saving and opening a Session file the Session.vim file does:

```
badd +1 file1
badd +1 file2
badd +1 file3
…
```

This result in buffer numbering starting with 2 instead of 1.

[image: :ls after opening Session file]

I notice some Session files use `badd +0` instead of `badd +1`, but this does not make any difference.

One way to circumvent this is to comment out first file in the session file and open Vim by:

```
vim file1 -S Session.vim
```

Is there a way to do this in the session-file instead?

I have tried to replace `badd` with `edit` for first file in Session.vim, but that does not work. (File does not get opened at all.)

---

VIM 8.0 patches: 1-1453

https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/vim

Also tested with `vim -u NONE -S`

Comment: I do not see it. What is your vim version?

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt: Debian/Ubuntu pkg. VIM - Vi IMproved 8.0 (2016 Sep 12, compiled Jun 06 2019 17:31:41) Included patches: 1-1453

Comment: can you please check with a more uptodate version?

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt: I compiled my own on previous Ubuntu as there was some irritating bugs they were slow to include (released) fixes for. Perhaps I have to do it here as well.

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt: I do not have the time to do it now. Have wasted too much time on this rabbit-hole heh. I can do it later and report back if you want.

Answer (score 0):

I could achieve that by moving the `edit` line from the middle of the session file to the first line of the file. Ugly, I'd say...